# Laravel 503 at index.php

Tags: laravel, docker, http-status-code-503, laravel-sail

I have an install of Laravel running in sail, a mate has the same project (Laravel 9) and it runs fine on his system but on mine I get a 503. The error is occurring at this point in the index.php file…

```
$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();
```

I can successfully dd before this block but it falls over with a 503 if I move the dd to be after it.

Can I also add that I have other development sites that run fine on my machine.

Any help on where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Gary

Comment: which PHP Version you run?

Comment: I’m running php 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working by moving he project to an external drive that is configured to be case sensitive.